# Python Flask wont print

Tags: python, flask

Whenever i try to print something in flask it simply wont work

```
@app.route('/ControllerInputAxes/<first_x>/<first_y>/<second_x>/<second_y>')
def update_controller(first_x, first_y, second_x, second_y):
  print('asdfhj')
  return 0
```

print('asdfhj') wont print
it comes up with

```
    127.0.0.1 - - [13/Nov/2023 22:28:33] "POST /ControllerInputAxes/0/0/0/0 HTTP/1.1" 405 -
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Nov/2023 22:28:33] "POST /ControllerInputButtons/false/false/false/false/false/false/false/false/false/false/false/false/false/false/false/false/false HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

i tried to use

```
print('asdfhj', flush=True)
```

becuase i searched it up and it said that is what you should do, if anyone knows what to thanks that would be helpful

Comment: What happens instead? What is the output on console? What is the result of http request?

Comment: i changed the question for you to see

Answer (score 0):

[Error 405](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405) signifies `Method Not Allowed` - that means the request you are sending is of incorrect type (types being POST, GET, DELETE, PUT).

```
[13/Nov/2023 22:28:33] "POST /ControllerInputAxes/0/0/0/0 HTTP/1.1" 405
```

You can see in server logs that you are sending `POST`. As you can read in [Flask docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#flask.Flask.route), `@app.route` by default accepts only `GET` requests. That's the reason your function is not being run. You need to replace `@app.route('...')` with `@app.route('...', methods=["GET", "POST"])` if you want to accept `POST`s as well.